# Cómo reemplazar valores con objetos en anotaciones de Java

Tags: java

Estoy trabajando con MyBatis, el siguiente código funciona:

```
@Select(GET_USER_DATA)
@Results(value = {
    @Result(property="webUserId",javaType=String.class,column="id_usuario_web"),
    @Result(property="webUserType",javaType=String.class,column="tipo_usuario_web"),
    @Result(property="webUserLastname",javaType=String.class,column="apellidos")
})
WebUser getUserData(@Param("login") final String login, @Param("password") final String password);
```

Pero quiero hacer algo más elegante así que intenté lo siguiente:

```
@Select(GET_USER_DATA)
@Results(value = {
    @Result(WebUserTable.WEB_USER_ID.getResultObject()), 
    @Result(WebUserTable.WEB_USER_TYPE.getResultObject()),
    @Result(WebUserTable.WEB_USER_LASTNAME.getResultObject())
})
WebUser getUserData(@Param("login") final String login, @Param("password") final String password);
```

Para esto cree un `enum` en mi clase:

```
enum WebUserTable{

    WEB_USER_ID("webUserId", Integer.class, "usuario_web_id"),
    WEB_USER_TYPE("webUserType", String.class, "tipo_usuario_web"),
    WEB_USER_LASTNAME("webUserLastname",String.class,"apellidos");

    private Object result;

    WebUserTable(final String _property, final Class _javaType, final String _column){
        result = new Object(){
            String property = _property;
            Class javaType = _javaType;
            String column = _column;
        };
    }

    public final Object getResultObject() {
        return result;
    }   

};
```

Sin embargo obtengo este error: `This attribute value is undefined for the annotation type Result` en las líneas con `@Result`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No se puede hacer lo que intentas en Java. Las anotaciones tienen sus propiedades definidas y existen procesadores de las anotaciones que leerán dichas propiedades con sus tipos de datos establecidos. Lo que estás haciendo es reemplazar todas esas variables con un `enum`, lo cual no es soportado.

Para tu problema actual, te recomiendo que utilices la primera forma, que en mi opinión no es poco elegante.